# codeigniter get_where with mysql functions in check values

Tags: php, codeigniter

Just a question about the `get_where` function of codeigniter Active Records. I wanted to get a query which should be like this:

```
Select * from foo 
where date = STR_TO_DATE('$month/$day/$year','%m/%d/%Y') 
  and time = STR_TO_DATE('$hour:$minute$ampm', '%l:%i%p')
```

Now I created a function in my model which appears like this:

```
public function validate_if_existing($month,$day,$year,$hour,$minute,$ampm)
{
    $event_date = "STR_TO_DATE('$month/$day/$year','%m/%d/%Y')";
    $event_time = "STR_TO_DATE('$hour:$minute$ampm', '%l:%i%p')";

    $this->db->flush_cache();
    $query = $this->db->get_where('foo',array('event_date' => $event_date,'event_time'=> $event_time));

    return $query->num_rows();
}
```

But it returns `0` rows where I expected it to be `1`. I tried to check the `$event_date` and `$event_time` contents and it just appears exactly as I expected. Like this:

```
STR_TO_DATE('01/01/2012','%m/%d/%Y')
```

Am I doing this wrong? Anyway to solve this out?

Comment: run your original query above ( SQL ) against database first and see if it returns anything

Comment: yes it return a row based on the data I'd given.

Comment: The values would be escaped in the query. Run `$this->db->last_query();` and check the generated query.

Comment: First time I've heard of that one. Well here's the return query:
SELECT * FROM (`foo`) WHERE `event_date` = 'STR_TO_DATE(\'07/11/2012\',\'%m/%d/%Y\')' AND `event_time` = 'STR_TO_DATE(\'06:00pm\', \'%l:%i%p\')'. I think those unwanted slashed made the problem.

Comment: I have a doubt how time will save in db i think like this 03:45:15(hr:mm:sc)....but in your query you are calling like this hr:mmsc.........i think that may be problem

Answer (score 1):

got it already! I just manually added the filters using the `$this->db->where()` like this:

```
$this->db->where('event_date',"STR_TO_DATE('$month/$day/$year','%m/%d/%Y')", FALSE);
```

works just like in `$this->db->select()`. The  `$this->db->get_where()` is just a shortcut form. good to use when making a non complex query. Thanks to air4x for giving me some tips. :)

Comment: will this not be prone to sql injection attacks?